# How to reject user input if it is not valid and make him input again

Tags: c

I'm creating a program that asks for input and then based on the input rejects it or accepts it. This is the code:

```
    while(1){
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    if(name[0] == '\0'){
        printf("Input Cannot be empty\nExample: bobshmurda\n");
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
printf("Enter age: ");
scanf("%d", &age);

while(!age>= 15){
    printf("Age\n");
}

while(1){
    printf("Enter MMN: ");
    scanf("%d", &mmn);
    if (!cvv >= 3){
        printf("\nInvalid MMN... Try again\n");
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

while(1){
    printf("DOB: ");
    scanf("%d", &dob);
    if (!exp == 4){
        printf("Invalid DOB detected... Format: 0123\n");
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

What i basically want to do is i want to for example IF age is greater than 100 or less than 0 do this, etc. Same with strings how would i do that?

Comment: Could you describe what your code is doing wrong? Could you show us a test case where your code doesn't do what you want?

Comment: With `scanf("%s", &name)`, using the address-of operator `&` for the `"%s"` format is almost *always* wrong. If `name` is a pointer, then you get a pointer to the variable (a pointer to pointer). If `name` is an array you get a pointer to the array itself, which is semantically of the wrong type.

Comment: You also need to check what [`scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: Lastly, the condition `!age>= 15` in a loop where you don't even assign to `age` is wrong on many levels.

Comment: There are other possible problems as well, but I let you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to figure them out.

Comment: It is easier to validate (and reject) user input by using `fgets` and then applying `sscanf`. That prevents the input stream being blocked by data that can't be converted, such as "cat" entered when `%d` is expecting numeric data.

Answer (score 1):

A do-while loop is probably the simplest method:

```
int is_valid = 0;
do {
    // Get user input here
    is_valid = validate_input(...);
} while (! is_valid);

// Continue with processing...
```